# Convert Epoch Time format into date time - PHP

Tags: php, json, date, integer, date-formatting

value for date in JSON ($date = 1692148331336)
i want to convert that number into proper date format in php

I did like this
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s", substr("1692152884431", 0, 10));

i am getting out put as '2023-08-16 02:28:04' but time is not correct

Comment: Why isn't that correct? Make sure you have the time zone set correctly.

Comment: Instead of using `substr()`, divide `$date` by 1000.